# How to get name of Job in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to select name of job from which was called the function in which I need that query, but unfortunately I can`t figure it out, can somebody help me?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: Plz reframe your question. Not able to understand

Comment: I have function (called from different jobs), in which I collect some data and create a snapshot, snapshots are then inserted in table and in last run of job I want to create .zip from snapshots made by this job. So I need to add some unique identifier of job that calls my function for every snapshot made by this function.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you want to do can be done with a [User defined Context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5002.htm#SQLRF01202).

To be able to use a user defined context first of all you need to create a trusted procedure which will be used to set attributes in the context. We need to do this because dbms_session.set_context can't be used directly.

```
create procedure set_test_ctx
(
    p_attribute_name in varchar2,
    p_attribute_value in varchar2
) is
begin
    dbms_session.set_context(
       'test_ctx',
        p_attribute_name,
        p_attribute_value);
end;
/
```

After this we will create our context

```
create context test_ctx using set_test_ctx;
```

If you need to use this context with another user don't forget to issue a grant.

```
grant execute on set_test_ctx to test_user;
```

Now you can use the procedure to use the context and use the view "session_context" or the function SYS_CONTEXT to retreive the value.

```
execute set_test_ctx('ATTRIBUTE1', 'value1');

select value from session_context where namespace='TEST_CTX' and ATTRIBUTE='ATTRIBUTE1';

select  sys_context('TEST_CTX','ATTRIBUTE1') as value from dual;
```